Product of $R_i$-modules $M_i$ over $\prod_{i \in I} R_i$ for some index set $I$?
Need to clear a few basic notions.
The abstract (On property (A) for modules over direct product of rings, Bouchiba, El-Arabi, Quaest. Math., 2019) reads:
"If $\{R_i\}_{i \in I}$ is a family of commutative rings and $\{M_i\}_{i \in I}$ such that each $M_i$ is an $R_i$-module, then the direct product $\prod_{i \in I} M_i$ is an $\mathcal{A}$-module over $\prod_{i \in I} R_i$ if and only if each $M_i$ is an $\mathcal{A}$-module over $R_i$, $i \in I$..."
Added: The $\mathcal{A}$-module property holds for an $R$-module $M$ if each element of any finitely generated ideal $I$ annihilates some $m \in M \setminus \{0\}$ and $\{m \in M \setminus \{0\}: Im=0\} \neq \emptyset $. The stronger notion says that there is one such $m \in M \setminus \{0\}$ for any finite collection of such annihilators: $r_1m=...=r_n m=0$.
What construction should I assume in this case, no further limitation imposed on the index set? Please be overly clear.

What is the meaning of "$\mathcal{A}$-module" here? And what is your question? Are you just asking what the infinite direct product is? It is the infinite cartesian product with the pointwise $\prod R_i$-module structure.

If nothing else is specificed, the standard way to read it would be that $I$ is any set, that $\prod_{i\in I} M_i={g:I\to \bigcup_{i\in I} M_i,\mid,\forall i, g(i)\in M_i}$ endowed sum $(f+g)(i)=f(i)+g(i)$, that $\prod_{i\in I} R_i={a:I\to \bigcup_{i\in I} R_i,\mid,\forall i, a(i)\in R_i}$ with operations $(a+b)(i)=a(i)+b(i)$ and $(ab)(i)=a(i)b(i)$, and that the action of $\prod_{i\in I} R_i$ on $\prod_{i\in I} M_i$ is given by $(af)(i)=a(i)f(i)$.

@ Yuan & Giulio - thanks. Added some.
